# Creating a horizontal scrollable region inside of a Uitableviewcontroller

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiview, uiscrollview, swift4

I am working on a UITableviewController that has a scrollable region inside one of its cells. The idea is this region shows a series of icons, and it can be anywhere from 1 to 50+ icons in a row with equal spacing.

Can a UICollectionView be used, or must it be done purely programmatically with a horizontal scrollview and dynamically iterate through each item in the collection, manually create/add the view, wire up a click listener, etc? Maybe I can make a custom view that does this, and somehow dynamically insert it? Not sure how to go about this at all.

This is how the table looks. The red rectangle is the scrollable region within the first tablecell that can extend out indefinitely based upon the number of items in my collection.

---

[image]

The idea is you can just scroll to the right, find the images you want, and tap on them to mark them.

Thank you all very much for any help!

Comment: Of course you can use collection view. There is nothing wrong with it :)
Also, as I see this is controller with static cells, you can embed UICollectionViewController there, so any logic related to selecting those images will be in another controller, not cell/view/etc.

Comment: @MaksymMusiienko thanks will 1) the collectionview will scroll to the right if I set it to only have 1 row and N "columns" in the collection?  2) do you see any problems w/ this solution?  3) maybe you can write this as an answer and i'll mark you as correct so you get credit? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UICollectionView is definitely what you want to use here :)
Also, I see that your table view controller has static cells, which means you can embed UICollectionViewController instead of just view there, so any logic related to selecting those images will be in another controller, not cell/view/etc.

UICollectionView will scroll to the right, if you will have constant height.

P.S. Check [awesome article](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/posts/using-child-view-controllers-as-plugins-in-swift) about using child view controllers in your app.